# How can I describe something that is easy to improve?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Say I have a person who is fond of change/prone to progress or a technology that is designed to be easily changed and improved. What is an adjective I can use to describe both or either one of them?

I am trying list the advantages of synthetic organisms and want to express that they can easily improve themselves over a short period of time, as opposed to humans.

Usage:

> The key advantages of synthetic organisms are lack of emotions,
> apathy, ruthless pragmatism, exponential learning and [the fact that
> they are easy to improve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you example requires a noun rather than an adjective as you requested:

> The key advantages of synthetic organisms are lack of emotions,
> apathy, ruthless pragmatism, exponential learning and
> **updatability**.

**updatability**

> The condition of being updatable [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/updatability)

**updatable** (adj.)

> That may be updated. OED

**update** (v.)

> Make (something) more modern or up to date. [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=updatable%20definition%20modern&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&sxsrf=AOaemvKydIqXn2pnv39Yey9GpcknOCEL6g%3A1634256336507&ei=0MVoYauhHq-JwbkPnuCWQA&ved=0ahUKEwiryaKjj8vzAhWvRDABHR6wBQgQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=updatable%20definition%20modern&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgAToHCCMQsAMQJzoHCAAQRxCwAzoGCAAQDRAeOgYIABAWEB46CAgAEA0QBRAeOgoIABANEAUQChAeOggIABAIEA0QHkoFCDoSATFKBAhBGABQmg5Y6RZgyhpoAXAAeACAAY8BiAHhBpIBAzAuN5gBAKABAcgBCcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz)

> If you update something, you make it more modern, usually by adding
> new parts to it or giving new information. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/update)

---

> Each prospective logic agent is equipped with a knowledge base and a
> moral theory as its initial **updatable** state [Robert Trappl; *A
> Construction Manual for Robots' Ethical Systems*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Construction_Manual_for_Robots_Ethical/8ewLCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=robots%20are%20updatable)

> Buy services instead of products—such as leasing services for office
> equipment, so manufacturers will produce durable, **updatable**
> products, rather than ones that are obsolete in a few years.  [Joanna
> Yarrow; *How to Reduce Your Carbon Footprint*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/How_to_Reduce_Your_Carbon_Footprint/coSKtrw5Q7sC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=updatable%20products&pg=PA78&printsec=frontcover)

> The objectives in sustainable product design in the Finnish
> manufacturing industry are seen as making products modular and
> **updatable**. [Günther Seliger; *Sustainable Manufacturing*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sustainable_Manufacturing/TgNj_YW3grIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=updatable%20products&pg=PA305&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 2):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/adaptable) has a word that is applicable to people and to technology:

> **adaptable**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> **1** Able to adjust to new conditions.
> *rats are highly adaptable to change*
>
> **1.1** Able to be modified for a new use or purpose.
> *telephone links that are adaptable for modems*

The example could be

> The key advantages of synthetic organisms are lack of emotions, apathy, ruthless pragmatism, exponential learning and **adaptability**.

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas have to be combined in this adjective, the possibility of being improved and the easiness of any improvement; it is not likely that such a term exists. However a combination of words is possible.

> ([vocabulary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/meliorative)) **meliorative** adjective
> tending to ameliorate
> synonyms: ameliorating, ameliorative, amelioratory
> bettering
> changing for the better

- The key advantages of synthetic organisms are lack of emotions, apathy, ruthless pragmatism, exponential learning and their *being readily meliorative*.

Answer (score 0):

If something has lots of room for improvement then it has not yet reached its optimal point of development .  You could say “and their low level of initial optimization” or “and their sub-optimal initial state.”